# Can I dynamically change a kml polyline color? (in v2)

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-maps-api-2

I have a KML file rendered in a Google Map using:

```
geoXml = new GGeoXml('postcodes.kml');
map.addOverlay(geoXml);
```

The LineStyle colour of the Polygon is set within the KML file.

I would like to dynamically change it (preferable when switching between Map / Satellite / Hybrid), but failing that, just via my own link outside of the map.

Any ideas how this can be done please? (google maps v2)

Answer (score 0):

The Maps API can't change the styles of a KML file. You also likely want to switch to using Maps API V3, since V2 is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks Mano, I guess I will need a duplicate KML file with different colours, and do toggle between them as overlays. Thanks yes I'm aware of the deprication and will do so in due course.